# Looking for HowTos or Examples of Presentation Platforms targeting Management/Clients

Tags: qgis, google-earth, open-source-gis, geolocation

Any good ideas about using Google Earth to present self contained geospatial data&app to a client or senior management?

The broader issue being explored here is that many of our clients are not likely to maintain GIS systems themselves, or be competent enough to install a free app and then browse the data. And we would like the legacy we leave to a client to be independent of us, so we don't want them to be relying on our server or any one else's server. A single file container (yes I know you will say SpatiaLite but what app?) that can be USB'd or the like.

One feature I really like in GE, is to geolocate photos and have them appear on the map, to provide a record, or some interactivity etc. I can do the same in QGIS, but not without knowing a lot about the installation. In GE, I know that if they have got the KMZ, they will find the photos.

And what about senior management? Because you know they are luddites at best, won't have time to view it when you have time etc.

So my thought here is to put GE up as the app, and KMZ as the container, and ask the question in this forum.

What is the best example of GE (or your choice app) as a self contained presentation?

Comment: "so we don't want them to be relying on our server or any one else's server." ... Google Servers (for GE) are fine?

Comment: Well we are only asking the minimum from Google, the ubiquitous viewer, and the current imagery. It think ubiquity is a very useful concept in this discussion.  Obviously the particular data for the project could become "ephemeral" if it was held on a third party server. We want the client to hold the specific project data in any way they choose (but unfortunately round here that will be on local disk of some sort....).

Comment: For some insight into the type of presentation which should be delivered to management....  see www.Dilbert.com for the 1st Sept.....

Answer (score 2):

I have had good experience using both KMZ/GE and [ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/home/) methods for sharing GIS data to both inner managment and clients.

As you may know GE involves a install on the user end whereas ArcGIS Online, users have  to create a ESRI global account to view your shared map.

Comment: I was going to suggest arcgisonline. Some may not see that as open. But as it is free I think a good solution for BWill. Also I noticed they just added kmz and csv support for loading your own data. So, If you don't have your own sde/ags datasource, file sources are beginning to be added. Not sure if we will see spatialite though

Comment: Also the presentation mode on arcgisonline is pretty nifty.  a slide show with interactive maps is kinda the bestof both worlds.